# MVC C# AJAX Post routing issue

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am from ASP Classic background and new to MVC object-oriented programming especially their re-routing config. I do understand the Model View Controller concept.

I am having the following issue:

When my view is at `Password.chtml` and heading to detail `PasswordDet.chtml` either from

`button [New] will be http://localhost:50218/Password/PasswordDet` OR

`button [Edit] will be http://localhost:50218/Password/PasswordDet/123`

The URL syntax on AJAX postback to trigger back `PasswordController/PasswordDet` is different depends on whether you come from `[New]` or `[Edit]` in order for the postback to work.

My understanding is that now I am at PasswordDet.chtml. Triggering `PasswordController/PasswordDet/` shouldn't it be  `var url = 'PasswordDet/' + $("#btnSubmit").val()`? Or please share what is the correct way. Please help thank you.

The following is an illustration of my problem.

[image]

**From `Password.chtml` to `PasswordDet.chtml` I have:**

**New**

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("PasswordDet", "Password")';
```

**Edit**

```
"render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
     return '<a href="/Password/PasswordDet/' + full.AutoINC + '"><img src="../../Content/myPics/edit-2-24.png" ></a>';
 }
```

But in order for it to work. At `PasswordDet.html` AJAX Postback

From `New` I need to put `PasswordDet/` infront :

```
 var url = 'PasswordDet/' + $("#btnSubmit").val()
```

And From `Edit` I don't need to:

```
 var url = $("#btnSubmit").val()
```

**Shouldn't both of them the same**

**AjaxCode at PasswordDet.chtml**

```
var url = 'PasswordDet/' + $("#btnSubmit").val()
var formData = $('#formPassDet').serialize();

$.ajax({

     url: url,
     type: "POST",
     data: formData,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (response) {

         if (response.status == "saved") {

     *****Here i don't need to put '.../"  ******************
            window.location.href = 'Password';

         } else if (response.status == "updated") {

     *****Here i have to put************************ 
            window.location.href = '../Password/';
   });
```

**Password Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PasswordDet(string id, ForgotPasswordModel viewModel)
    {
      some  code
    }
```

**RouteConfig Not sure how to use this**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: you mean to on `edit` and `new` redirect page to different page right using ajax ?

Comment: @Lalji, New and Edit will got to `PasswordDet` it is when I do a Ajax post back the URL is all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Actually not clear what u need.If you are a beginner in MVC
pls go through the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCNyL4LfWSw

Comment: all I need is to actually generalize the URL syntax, why do I have use different syntax pointing to the same controllers or view?